# Can I use WinMerge to compare *.class files?

Tags: winmerge

I used to work with `BeyondCompare` and it was able to compare `*.class` files by configuring it to run a decompiler before comparison.

Is there something like that for `WinMerge`? Or a plug-in that can do it instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have spent the day writing a DLL plugin for Winmerge to do this - it isn't the world's greatest thing, but it gets the job done.

Takes the filename, splits it into directory and class name, then calls javap for each class file. It is rather slow unfortunately (javap's fault I'd say).

It would be nice if winmerge compared the files before unpacking them to see if they are different - that would save a bit of time. Maybe this can be accomplished in the plugin somehow but as I said I really just hacked this together as quick as I could.

Source, prebuilt DLL, and instructions here:
https://gitlab.com/wayneuroda/winmerge-unpack-java-class-files

Comment: Thanks - I missed the notification about this answer, i just saw it now. I really appreciate your effort - I'll test it ASAP :)

Comment: to enable automatic diffing (upon double clicking), do this (Plugins > Automatic Unpacking) - WinMerge 2.14.0

Comment: @GaryTsui thanks, but what I mean is that in the list view (say you compare a whole folder of class files) it will show class files as different, even though upon unpacking they are identical. I think this comes about because they can have binary differences (due to recompilation etc) however the method/field signatures have not changed. When comparing two binary APIs for example, you have to check every different class manually, when you double click on it you will be met with "the files are identical" or similar, even though they were marked as different in the list!

Comment: great trick .. you save my night :)

Comment: The links seems to be broken :(

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi I updated the links

Comment: publishing it to github, gitlab or any similar sites would be far more reliable than a onedrive link

Comment: @phuclv I love gitlab, but I feel the urge to make a joke about how nobody has yet deleted the onedrive database ;) you're right. Dunno why I never did publish this. I don't feel it's very polished. Will put it on my todo list.

Answer (score 1):

If comparing disassembled JVM bytecode (see my other answer) is not enough, maybe decompiling to Java source code might be more helpful…

After learning about the "currently undocumented" `Plugins.xml` ([Plugins in the improved plugin system](https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge/discussions/948)) as an alternative to `sct` and `dll` plugins, I have sucessfully "created" a plugin decompiling Java `*.class` files using [procyon Java Decompiler](https://github.com/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java-Decompiler) in *WinMerge* 2.16.30.0:

1. Create directory `%APPDATA%\WinMerge\MergePlugins`, if it doesn't exist.
2. Create file `%APPDATA%\WinMerge\MergePlugins\Plugins.xml`, if it doesn't exist.

   - Use `C:\Program Files\WinMerge\MergePlugins\Plugins.xml` as template removing `<plugin>` elements.
3. Insert a custom `<plugin>` with your path\to\procyon-decompiler.jar:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugins>
  <plugin name="MyDecompileJavaClass">
    <event value="FILE_PACK_UNPACK" />
    <description value="My JVM class decompiler with Procyon. &#xD;&#xA;Arguments: Command line options passed to the java command." />
    <file-filters value="\.class$" />
    <is-automatic value="false" />
    <unpacked-file-extension value=".class.java" />
    <extended-properties value="ProcessType=Decompilation;MenuCaption=My Decompile Java Class" />
    <arguments value="A:\path\to\procyon-decompiler.jar" />
    <unpack-file>
      <command>cmd /c java -jar ${*} "${SRC_FILE}" > "${DST_FILE}"</command>
    </unpack-file>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

5. Reload plugins (*WinMerge* menu command).
6. If necessary, adjust the path to Procyon JAR (arguments) in *WinMerge* plugin settings.
7. Use the new plugin for unpacking/comparing in *WinMerge*.

Comment: Wow, this is so much nicer to the user than making them write a DLL :D

Answer (score 0):

The [DecompileJVM plugin](https://manual.winmerge.org/en/Plugins.html#Plugins_DisassembleJVM) `DisassembleJVM` has been added in [WinMerge 2.16.15 - 2021-09-20](https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge/blob/v2.16.30/Docs/Users/ChangeLog.md#winmerge-21615---2021-09-20).
Look for "Disassemble JVM Bytecode" in the list of plugins.

It is an unpacker plugin allowing you to compare JVM bytecode disassembled with `javap`.